# R shiny slider increments

Tags: r, slider, shiny

Trying to setup a slider bar range from 0.5 - 999.5 with increments of 1 such that the range of values that it can take on is 0.5, 1.5, 2.5 ... 999.5 .  My problem is that when I use the the slider from the code below, I get values including whole integer 1, 2, 3, 4...etc   I have tried changing the steps to 0.5 but then I get, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 ...etc.  Any ideas?

```
column(4,
         fileInput("pbs", label = ("PBS File input")),
         sliderInput("size", 
                     label = ("Size Range Selection"), 
                     min = 0.5, 
                     max = 999.5, 
                     value = c(0.5,999.5),
                     step = 1,
                    round = F

         )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is not the greatest, but it will work:

In your `ui`:

```
  sliderInput("size", 
                     label = ("Size Range Selection"), 
                     min = 0, 
                     max = 999, 
                     value = c(0,999),
                     step = 1,
                    round = F,
                    post=".5"
         )
```

This will show a slider that goes from 0 to 999, but it adds ".5" to the labels so it will look like 0.5 to 999.5.

Then, in your `server`, you will have to add .5 to each of the values from the slider before using the numbers.

Comment: Thanks I was hoping there will be a build-in way to do this.  This solved my problem thanks!

Comment: I was hoping that too, but unfortunately it looks like there is not.